# Modifying a bst file to allow for an arxiv field

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to add an `arxiv` reference to my bibentries and I would like to control how it shows up in the citation.

I would like to have the field only contain the informative part:

```
arxiv = 0809.0726
```

but for the result to be more informative and perhaps contain a link:

```
\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0726}{arXiv:0809.0726}
```

which, of course can be done with a macro:

```
\newcommand{\arxiv}[1]{{ \href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#1}{arXiv:#1}}}
\arxiv{0809.0726}
```

S far so good.

I've taken `unsrt.bst` and started modifying it.

1. I've added `arxiv` to the ENTRY list
2. I've added a `format.arxiv` function that is a model for what I want:

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.arxiv}
   { arxiv empty$
        { "" }
        {" {\url{arXiv:" * arxiv * "}}" * }
     if$
   }
   ```
3. I modify the relevant output functions to call arxiv.output (for example, `unpublished`):

   ```
    FUNCTION {unpublished}
    { output.bibitem
     format.authors "author" output.check
     new.block
     format.title "title" output.check
     new.block
     note "note" output.check
     new.block
     format.arxiv output
     format.date output
     fin.entry
    }
   ```

However, when I try to compile a file I get the error:

```
Running `BibTeX' on `ResearchStatement' with ``bibtex ResearchStatement''
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (Web2C 7.5.6)
The top-level auxiliary file: ResearchStatement.aux
The style file: myunsrt.bst
Database file #1: general.bib
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry FarjounSchaeffer2010
while executing---line 963 of file myunsrt.bst
(There was 1 error message)

BibTeX exited abnormally with code 2 at Thu Nov 10 16:39:09
```

I tried playing with the `*`'s in the `format.arxiv` function, but I kept getting the wrong results

I'm sure this is easy for those who can access the force...but I am still a grasshopper here...

Comment: Have you looked into modifying the `url` field, supplied by, say, the plainnat.bst file?

Comment: Have you checked out these styles: http://arxiv.org/hypertex/bibstyles/ ? Apropos of your approach,  there is already a version of `unsrt.bst` modified to show eprint numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Try placing the following in the .bst file. (The upper function may already be present).

```
FUNCTION {format.primaryClass}
{
  primaryClass empty$
      { "" }
      { " [" primaryClass * "]" *}
  if$            
}

FUNCTION {format.archive}
{
  archivePrefix empty$
      { "" }
      { archivePrefix ":" *}
  if$            
}

FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{ eprint empty$
     { ""}
     { archive empty$
          {"\textit{Preprint:}\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/" eprint * "}" * 
             "{{ " * format.archive * eprint *
              format.primaryClass * "}}" *}
          {"\href{" archive *  "/" * eprint * "}" * 
             "{{ " * format.archive * eprint *
              format.primaryClass * "}}" *}
     if$
     }
     if$
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  format.date output
  new.block
  format.note "note" output.check
  format.eprint output
  fin.entry
}
```

Comment: I generated my own bst file in the usual way when I wrote my thesis, but wanted something similar to what you want. I got my hack on and this was the result. Honestly, I'm not 100% certain of how it's working now, but looks fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Mark, is a complete working example, but I had my way of doing things and I therefore wanted an answer on how to fix my code...not a different code...but looking at his code I managed to figure out that there was a spurious `*` in my definition, which then pulled too many items from the stack. The `format.arxiv` function that I ended up using is:

```
 FUNCTION {format.arxiv}
{ arxiv empty$
    { "" }
    {"\href{www.arxiv.org/abs/" arxiv *  "}" * 
             "{\tt arXiv:" * arxiv *  "}" *}
  if$
}
```

Notice the lack of a `*` between the first two arguments of the false clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file unsrt-phys.bst in the link below:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8AqjYFfBKw0dEZXcFN0WEVIN0U&authuser=0
and put it in the folder of your article. Then change the style of bibliography to `\bibliographystyle{unsrt-phys}`.
Run Bibtex, and enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
FUNCTION {format.arxiv}
{ arxiv empty$
    { "" }
    { "{\url{arXiv:" arxiv * "}}" * }
  if$
}
```

and, of course, an entry `arxiv` in the list `ENTRY`. Then I get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{demo,
    author="foo",
    title="bar",
    arxiv="1234.5678"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]