# Bst file compatible with arxiv, kp.bst like

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I want to have the following features in my bibliography :

- To display something like : `arxiv:refnumb` with a link to the actual article in a browser, working for both old and new identifiers
- Together with others things as numerical numbering and other cosmetic preferences

I can create a bst file with the wonderful website http://www.podoblaz.net/cml/ and I can obtain exactly what I want to have the features of the second point of the list, but the arxiv stuff is not displayed as I would like.

On another hand, there is the kp.bst style that do exactly what I want for linking to arxiv articles, except that it doesn't support all the identifiers and also it is quite ugly in my opinion.

How can I proceed ? I tried to change the bst files to get what I want but it doesn't work and I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: Might [Modifying a bst file to allow for an arxiv field](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34411/35864) help you at all? Alternatively, [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) does also provide extensive arXiv support and is very easily customisable.

Comment: Well, I can try again modify my bst file but it was not very successful when I tried the first time. And what is biblatex ? Never heard of it. Can it be used with Lyx ?

Comment: What exactly did you modify in your file, what was not successful? `biblatex` [seems to work with Lyx](http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex).